# ado.net OdbcCommand string

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, odbc

I have a database accessible via ODBC and I am trying to connect using ADO.NET's OdbcConnection class.

When I try to execute this query

```
DbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 5 * from table LIMIT ORDER BY column1"
```

It returns the entire table and not the TOP 5.

I also tried using LIMIT at the end of the query, and yet it does not filter down my query.

How can I limit the result of my query down to just a couple few?

Thanks

Comment: What is the database ? By the way you example is wrong. Or you use TOP or LIMIT not both. Is it a typo?

Comment: @Steve It is not a typo in SQL Server, `LIMIT` becomes alias for `table`

Comment: @dotnetom If you are using MYSQL, then LIMIT is a keyword, why would he even use it as an alias?